# How do we assign FK to a newly loaded data in fact table?

Tags: sql-server, database-design, dimensional-modeling, facttable

While reading up on SQL, I got confused on how a newly loaded data into the fact table will get its FK. Say using the example below (image taken from Google):

[image]

This is my thoughts on how the data is loaded

1. `SaleID` is auto generated (eg incremental) to give a unique ID to the new row
2. `SalesQuantity`, `SalesPrice`, `SalesAmount`, `ReceiptID`, `TimeStamp` are loaded into the `factSales`

The question is how does this newly loaded data knows what FK (`DateKey`, `CustomerKey`, `StoreKey`, `ProductKey`) it should add? My understanding of a dimension table is that it describe the data in `factSales`.

For example, `dimDate` will have pre-populated date data up to year 2050. If a date data is loaded into `factSales`, where it should be in `TimeStamp` with a data such as `2020-05-01 13:00`, how can the `FK1 DateKey` know how to auto assign it to the date 2020-05-01? The same goes for other dimensions such as `CustomerKey`, where there will already exist some customer data.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You join the sales staging table to the dimensions using the business keys present in the source data to resolve the dimension keys, eg you load FactSales with a query like:

```
select d.DateKey, c.CustomerKey, s.SalesQuantity, s.SalesPrice
from stage.factSales s
left join dimDate d
  on d.FullDate = cast(s.TimeStamp as Date)
left join dimCustomer c
  on c.BusinessKey = s.CustomerNumber
```

Comment: Thanks David. To make sure I understand correctly, my source data should have 9 data (except the PK, and assuming all are `not null`). If my source data has a `DateKey` `20220101`, my `dimDate` table should have this `20220101` `Datekey` in PK before this source data loaded into `factSales`? May I confirm that by `sales staging table` you mentioned, it refers to the `factSales`?

Comment: Yes, you load your dimensions first.  And, no, Sales Staging Table is your raw source data.  `factSales` is where you load the data after you have joined the dimensions to find all the dimension keys to load into the fact table.

Comment: I see. I don't see staging tables in ERD examples (such as this example in this post). Is a staging table a "fixed" table in a data warehouse/mart setup or it is created each time a new raw data comes in temporary? Shouldn't it be shown in ERD?

Comment: Typically a "fixed" table designed to hold the raw source system data.  Often not shown in the ERD for a dimensional model.

Comment: Thanks David, appreciate your time!